# Alexa skill sends request to wrong skill

Tags: node.js, json, alexa-skills-kit

For some reason the Alexa simulator started sending request to other skills. I can invoke my skill, receive the response, then whatever intent I try to use I get an audio only response. I checked the server logs (Heroku hosted) and I can see that It did not receive any requests. Then I checked the device logs in the simulator and I can see this with the key **Directive: SkillDebugger.CaptureDebuggingInfo**:

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
        "name": "CaptureDebuggingInfo",
        "messageId": "77e1883a-d78d-43c2-a039-664eb0247955"
    },
    "payload": {
        "skillId": null,
        "timestamp": "2019-12-05T21:40:50.588Z",
        "dialogRequestId": "97b774bc-c1e8-48a4-9b73-09b84047756c",
        "skillRequestId": null,
        "type": "ConsideredIntents",
        "content": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "<IntentForDifferentSkill>",
                    "confirmationStatus": null,
                    "slots": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "<IntentForDifferentSkill>",
                    "confirmationStatus": null,
                    "slots": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "<IntentForDifferentSkill>",
                    "confirmationStatus": null,
                    "slots": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried all kind of stuff like changing the endpoint then putting it back or changing the invocation name and of course rebuilding a lot of times. But non of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

Is your skill session being kept open?  e.g. via responseBuilder.withShouldEndSession(false).

If your skill session ends then your skills intents will not be considered.

But if your skill session is still going then yes it is very strange that your skills intents are not matching.  Have you tried using 'Evaluate Model|Utterance Profiler' to make sure that your intent model is built and recognizing your inputs?

Comment: Well after the invocation the session should be kept open without me explicitly telling it to stay open, isn't it? However I came to the same conclusion that the session gets closed for some reason since telling the simulator "tell my skill that .. " (not sure about the term but invocation + intent) works perfectly

Comment: You are correct, the simulator and devices do not treat timeouts the same.. the simulator will keep the session alive very long whereas devices perform a reprompt or close the session after about ~8 seconds of inactivity.

You might try adding silence SSML to your prompt which will keep the session open longer, but the microphone will not turn on until the SSML finishes or user says the wake word again.  For some scenarios this is a viable workaround. 

If this isn't viable for you, you might like to add to https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote